# How to change the namespace of a function label from something other than Global?

Tags: ghidra

When I hit "L" at an address at the start of a function I can enter a name in field "Enter Name:"

There's also a "Namespace" dropdown, but the only value in this dropdown is "Global" and there seems to be no way to enter a new namespace name.

How can I change the namespace for the label to something other than Global?

Found the function label in the Symbol Tree, Right Clicked and choose "Create Namespace."  Namespace is under function label in Symbol Tree.

Hit L again on function label, only Global is a choice in dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix the name of the function with the namespace. For example, you can rename a function to `MyNamespace::MyFunction` to place the function `MyFunction` in the namespace `MyNamespace`.